# Proceso finalizado con codigo 3, ¿manipulacion incorrecta de memoria?

Tags: c++11

No es nada del otro mundo, una simple lista enlazada de un solo sentido que tiene que auto ordenarse ni bien le ingreses cualquier elemento, lo estoy empezando a hacer pero no soy capaz de conseguir enlazar los nodos correctamente. El problema es que no entiendo porque se auto destruyen los elementos al iterarlos si todos son nodos que están fuera del ámbito del for.
 Estoy confundido, necesito que alguien me explique.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;

    Node() = default;
    explicit Node(int val) : data{val}, next{} {}
    ~Node() = default;
};

int main() {
    // declaring
    auto *a = new Node{4};
    auto *b = new Node{2};
    auto *c = new Node{3};
    auto *d = new Node{5};
    auto *e = new Node{1};

    // linking
    a->next = b;
    b->next = c;
    c->next = d;
    d->next = e;

    // sorting
    for (auto &it{a} ; it->next != nullptr; it = it->next) {
        if (it->data < it->next->data) {
            auto *tmp = new Node();
            tmp->data = it->data;
            tmp->next = it->next;
            it = it->next;
            it->next = tmp;
        }
    }

    // printing
    for (auto &it{a}; it != nullptr; it = it->next) {
        std::cout << it->data << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```